# Let $f$ be continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$. Then, $F(x)=\max\{f(t):0\leq t\leq x\}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$ and

\begin{align} F(x)=\max\{f(t):0\leq t\leq x\}.  \end{align}
I want to show that $F(x)$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$.

**MY WORK**

Let $\epsilon> 0$ be given and $x_0\in [0,1].$ Since f is continuous at $x_0\in [0,1],$ then $\forall x\in [0,1]$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ it implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$

Also, \begin{align} |f(t)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon, \text{whenever}\; |t-x_0|<\delta,\;\forall\; t\in[0,x]\end{align}

Taking max over $t\in[0,x]$, we have 
\begin{align} \max|f(t)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon, \text{whenever}\; |t-x_0|<\delta,\;\forall\; t\in[0,x]\end{align}
\begin{align} |\max f(t)-\max f(x_0)|<\epsilon, \text{whenever}\; \max|t-x_0|<\delta,\;\forall\; t\in[0,x]\end{align}
\begin{align} |F(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon, \text{whenever}\; |x-x_0|<\delta\end{align}
which implies that $F(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1].$

I am very skeptical about this proof of mine. Please, is this proof correct? If no, a better proof is desired. Thanks!

Comment: There are issues in the last three "equations" you wrote. More precisely in the implication to move from one to the next one. **A very important principle in maths. Explain (at least to yourself) what theorem, axiom... you use when you move from one affirmation to the next one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wring because you cannot take maximum over $t \in [0,x]$ in an inequality which is valid only for $|x-t| <\delta$. Here are some hints for a correct proof. Verify that $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq \max \{|f(t)-f(s)|:x\leq t \leq y, x\leq t \leq y\}$ for $x<y$ $\,\,$ ($\dagger$) . Once you do this you can use the fact that the continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous to prove that $F$ is also uniformly continuous. Hint for ($\dagger$) : if $x\leq t \leq y$ then $f(t)=f(x)+[f(t)-f(x)]$.

Comment: Sir @Kavi Rama Murthy! Please, I am not getting how you got this $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq \max \{|f(t)-f(s)|:x\leq t \leq y, x\leq t \leq y\}$ for $x<y$ $\,\,$ ($\dagger$) 
 Please, can you show me

Comment: In the hint I have given take max over $t$. You will get $\max_{x\leq t \leq y} f(t) \leq f(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$. Note that $f(x) \leq F(x)$ and $\max_{0\leq t \leq x} f(t) \leq F(x)$. Hence $F(y) \leq F(x) +\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$.

Comment: it seems $\max_{x\leq t \leq y}f(t)\leq F(y)$. How you get left hand $F(y)\leq$?

Comment: If max over $[0,x]$ and max over $[x,y]$ are both $\leq M$ for some number $M$ then max over $[0,y]$ is $\leq M$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Please Sir, how about $[f(t)-f(x)]$ that changed to $|f(t)-f(x)|?$ I don't know why!

Comment: OK , I got it !

Comment: $[f(t)-f(x)]\leq |f(t)-f(x)|$.

Comment: @Riemann: Okay, thanks!

Comment: @Riemann: Please, can you help me break the hints down? I am stuck at this point $$\max\limits_{x\leq t\leq y}f(t)\leq F(x)+\max\limits_{x\leq t\leq y}|f(t)-f(x)|$$ I wouldn't be able to accept the answer if I don't understand every step. I am grateful for the help!

Comment: First,  $f(t)=f(x)+[f(t)-f(x)]\leq f(x)+|f(t)-f(x)|.$

So you can get
$\max_{x\leq t \leq y} f(t) \leq f(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$.
Using $f(x) \leq F(x)$, we can get 
$\max_{x\leq t \leq y} f(t) \leq F(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$.
Next, both  
$\max_{0\leq t \leq x} f(t)(=F(x))\leq F(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$ 
and
$\max_{x\leq t \leq y} f(t) \leq F(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$,
you will get $\max_{0\leq t \leq x} f(t)=F(y)\leq F(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|.$

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks very much for the explanation!

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Thanks a lot Sir! I am not trying to be rude by asking for explanation. Kindly forgive!

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks once again, but we've not yet arrived at the real equation. How do I get $|F(x)-F(y)|?$

Comment: @ Micheal:As we already get $F(y)\leq F(x)+\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$,
so $F(y)-F(x)\leq \max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|$,
it is easy to see that $\max_{x\leq t \leq y} |f(t)-f(x)|\leq\max_{s,t\in[x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|$. Then get the desired result.

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks very much! I did the other case and I got, $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq \max\limits_{s,t\in [x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|$. How do I use this to generalize for the whole interval? Do we have $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq \max\limits_{s,t\in [x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|\leq \max\limits_{s,t\in [0,1]}|f(s)-f(t)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|s-t|<\delta?$

Comment: From $f$ is continuous, we know $f$ is uniformly continuous. So for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, when $|x-y|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, so $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq \max\limits_{s,t\in [x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|\leq\epsilon$.(here $|s-t|\leq|x-y|<\delta$).Hence we know $F$ is uniformly continuous ,so $F$ is continuous.

Comment: @Riemann: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. Shouldn't it be $\forall\,s,t\in[0,1]$ at the end because if we conclude by $\max\limits_{s,t\in[x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|$, it means $f$ might not values in $[0,1]\[x,y].$ Hence, my usage of $\max\limits_{s,t\in[x,y]}|f(s)-f(t)|.$ I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by definition your function is monotone non-decreasing, hence it is enough to prove that it has no jumps.